# InDesign CC losing quality when importing image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, logo

Is it really possible that when you import image to InDesign its quality gets worse? In this case image contains logo made in Photoshop. We are using iMac which has retina screen I believe. What settings we should adjust at InDesign. No scaling should occur and that makes hard to understand why image gets so ugly.

Is there any tricks like using 600 DPI? now logo file is 300 DPI. End product is CD cover.

Logo is done at Illustrator and transferred to Photoshop and added some effects there.

Comment: What file format is your logo saved in and what is its resolution?

Comment: If you are copy'n'pasting or drag'n'dropping graphics into indesign, you may lose quality as it passes through the clipboard. Don't place graphics this way. Place them using "File > Place". This creates a LINK to the original graphic and does not alter the image unless you explicitly set inDesign to downsample during, say, a PDF export.

Comment: Those imported using Place. Tiff format is used. 300 DPI

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be to check your display settings:

[image: settings]

Display settings have no effect on the final output of your document, they merely control how detailed your images are displayed in-program.

Comment: High Quality Display is checked. Must be something else then.